# How do I install idlelib?

Tags: python, installation, pip, module, python-idle

How do I install `idlelib` in a windows computer?
Is there a way for me to install it with pip?

I am using

- Windows 7 (64-bit)
- Windows embeddable package (64-bit)
- Python 3.8.9

Thanks.

Because I am using Windows embedded version, it comes with nothing of that fancy stuff.

```
D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>python -m idlelib
D:\Installed\python-3.8.9\python.exe: No module named idlelib

D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>Lib\idlelib\idle.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>pip install idle3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement idle3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for idle3

D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>pip install python-idlelib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-idlelib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-idlelib

D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>pip install idlelib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement idlelib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for idlelib
```

```
D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>python -m idlelib
D:\Installed\python-3.8.9\python.exe: No module named idlelib

D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>python3 -m idlelib
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>py -m idlelib
'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>py3 -m idlelib
'py3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>
```

```
D:\Installed\python-3.8.9>echo %PATH%
D:\Installed\python-3.8.9\;D:\Installed\python-3.8.9\Scripts\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Installed\Execs\;D:\Installed\R-42-editor\bin\x64\;D:\Installed\poppler-0.68.0\bin\;D:\Installed\Java17\bin\
```

Answer (score 1):

Q. How do I install idlelib in a windows computer?

A. Get the standard 3.10 or 3.11 Windows installer from python.org, not the embeddable version. Run it.  Include the py launcher and tkinter/IDLE components.

Start IDLE from a command line with `py -m idlelib`, or from the Start menu IDLE entry on the python submenu, or from File Explorer right click on .py file, `Edit with IDLE`.

Q. Is there a way for me to install it with pip?

A. There may be alternate 3-party versions of idlelib on pypi.org, but IDLE requires tkinter, which requires _tkinter, which requires installation of the tcl/tk version that _tkinter was compiled against.  These are all left out of embedable python.  In other words, any variation of IDLE that you can install with pip requires that you already have tk/tkinter/IDLE installed with the standard installer.

I cannot say anything about Microsoft Store Python.